# Are these two Chinese words the same ( 更容易，才能)

Tags: characters

Could someone tell me if these two words in the image below are equivalent? The top word I grabbed from an image, the bottom word I am creating in photoshop by typing in what I believe is the correct characters: 更容易，才能 but can't seem to precisely match the 2nd to last character when it renders.

Is this a significant difference, or perhaps just a font-issue?

[image]

Comment: They're equivalent. Just different typefaces.

Answer (score 4):

Yes they are the same, just font issue.

Answer (score 3):

Could someone tell me if these two words in the image below are equivalent?

Yup.

Is this a significant difference, or perhaps just a font-issue?

Fonts.

The font Song might give you the desired result.

Answer (score 3):

Literally,

更容易 could mean easier or more easily,

才能 could mean then be able to (as a verb) or talent and ability (as a noun),

So I would say they are equivalent (i.e. more easily to do something or then we are able to do something) in a way, but not exactly interchangeable.

Comment: You might want to read the question again because your answer is completely irrelevant to the question.